# matrix-js-sdk setup and configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, matrix, sdk

I am having some issues trying to connect to a matrix server using the *matrix-js-sdk* in a react app.

I have provided a simple code example below, and made sure that credentials are valid (login works) and that the environment variable containing the URL for the matrix client is set. I have signed into element in a browser and created two rooms for testing purposes, and was expecting these two rooms would be returned from `matrixClient.getRooms()`. However, this simply returns an empty array. With some further testing it seems like the asynchronous functions provided for fetching room, member and group ID's only, works as expected.

According to https://matrix.org/docs/guides/usage-of-the-matrix-js-sd these should be valid steps for setting up the *matrix-js-sdk*, however the sync is never executed either.

```
const matrixClient = sdk.createClient(
        process.env.REACT_APP_MATRIX_CLIENT_URL!
);

await matrixClient.long("m.login.password", credentials);

matrixClient.once('sync', () => {
       debugger; // Never hit
}

for (const room of matrixClient.getRooms()) {
        debugger; // Never hit
}
```

I did manage to use the roomId's returned from `await matrixClient.roomInitialSync(roomId, limit, callback)`, however this lead me to another issue where I can't figure out how to decrypt messages, as the events containing the messages sent in the room seems to be of type `'m.room.encrypted'` instead of `'m.room.message'`.

Does anyone have any good examples of working implementations for the *matrix-js-sdk*, or any other good resources for properly understanding how to put this all together? I need to be able to load rooms, persons, messages etc. and display these respectively in a ReactJS application.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I simply forgot to run startClient on the matrix client, resulting in it not fetching any data.